# Regular expression to match integers up to 9 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression where only numbers are allowed with max length 9 and no minimum length. I came up with `\d{9}[0-9]` but it isn't working.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're close. Try this:

```
^\d{0,9}$
```

The ^ and $ match the beginning and the end of the text, respectively. `\d{0,9}` matches anywhere in the string, so `d0000` would pass because it would match the `0000` even though there is a d in it, which I don't think you want. That's why they ^$ should be in there.

Answer (score 14):

Regular expressions can be tricky; what you've written does the following:

- `\d` - digit
- `\d{9}` - exactly 9 digits
- `\d{9}[0-9]` - exactly 9 digits, followed by something between 0 and 9

If you want no minimum limit of length, but a maximum length of 9, you probably want the following regular expression:

- `\d{0,9}` - 0 to 9 digits

Comment: Nice explanation, is there anywhere else I can learn more about this though?

Answer (score 4):

I think It should be **1** to 9 digits:

```
^\d{1,9}$
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were close, try `\d{0,9}`.

Comment: Happy to help, also both vcsjones and NT3RP provided some nice details in their posts.