# RegEx to find exactly 4 digits number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text similar to the text below. It contains a `4` digits number that follows either `digit-` or `whitespace` and is followed by either `.`, `?`, `-digit` or `whitespace`.

---

I need to match all of the digits in the first paragraph but none in the second since those digits do not meet my conditions.

`Lorem ipsum 3400-digit, sit amet 5000 consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, explicabo 6700? Itaque iure  ipsum laboriosam, ex  nemo delectus iste quia cupiditate digit-9134? Iste nam digit-2456 at voluptate est 8456-digit? At excepturi quis voluptatibus 7500.`

`Lorem ipsum $5000  dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati tempora dolorum repellat reiciendis cum soluta deserunt ex voluptatibus, nam illum veniam £5550 quidem aperiam sequi, nostrum sed? Quidem eveniet maiores #5550 autem. https://codepen.io/pen/5000/3454`

---

There are a few similar questions already on *StackOverflow*. I have gone through some of them(links below), but I still can not do this. Please before marking this question as duplicate, check if your solution finds all the occurrence of the 4 digits number in the first paragraph but none in the second paragraph.

- [regular expression to match exactly 5 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975644/regular-expression-to-match-exactly-5-digits)
- [Regular expression to match integers up to 9 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229906/regular-expression-to-match-integers-up-to-9-digits)
- [RegEx match exactly 4 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674717/regex-match-exactly-4-digits)
- [JavaScript: \\d{4} RegExp allows more than 4 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614215/javascript-d4-regexp-allows-more-than-4-digits)

Comment: Is there `3400-digit` exactly as a word `digit`, or is it, e.g. `3400-456`? Are expected matches `3400`, `5000`, `6700`, `9134`, `2456`, `8456` and  `7500`?

Comment: It is `3400-digit` , `5000-digit`, or `*-digit` .

Comment: So, these captured texts [`(?:\bdigit-|\s|^)(\d{4})(?=[.?\s]|-digit\b|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/5i5fHg/1), right?

Comment: Thanks very much! It seems that it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
/(?:\bdigit-|\s|^)(\d{4})(?=[.?\s]|-digit\b|$)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5i5fHg/2). You need to get all Group 1 values.

**Details**

- `(?:\bdigit-|\s|^)` - either `digit-` (as a whole word), whitespace or start of string
- `(\d{4})` - Group 1: four digits
- `(?=[.?\s]|-digit\b|$)` - immediately to the right, there must be a `.`, whitespace, `?` , `-digit` (as a whole word) or end of string. **NOTE** Without a lookahead, consecutive whitespace-separated matches will be left out.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ["Lorem ipsum 3400-digit, sit amet 5000 consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, explicabo 6700? Itaque iure  ipsum laboriosam, ex  nemo delectus iste quia cupiditate digit-9134? Iste nam digit-2456 at voluptate est 8456-digit? At excepturi quis voluptatibus 7500.", "Lorem ipsum $5000  dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati tempora dolorum repellat reiciendis cum soluta deserunt ex voluptatibus, nam illum veniam £5550 quidem aperiam sequi, nostrum sed? Quidem eveniet maiores #5550 autem. https://codepen.io/pen/5000/3454" ];
var rx = /(?:\bdigit-|\s|^)(\d{4})(?=[.?\s]|-digit\b|$)/gi;
for (var s of strs) {
   var m, res =[];
   while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
     res.push(m[1]);
   }
   console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: I have to more cases: text starts and ends with a 4 digits number. How to include these two cases in the regex expression. Sorry, I found this after testing (:

Comment: @mahan What are these test cases? My  current regex [handles these cases](https://regex101.com/r/5i5fHg/3).

Comment: A 4 digits number follows `>` and is followed by `<`. How to include these two cases in the regex expression.  (: https://regex101.com/r/DoRRXd/1

Comment: @mahan Like [`(?:\bdigit-|[\s>]|^)(\d{4})(?=[.?\s<]|-digit\b|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/DoRRXd/2)

Comment: I have still one more case. The number is follows  and is followed by `&nbsp;`. Thanks a lot for your time (:

Comment: This works well. But isn't it possible to omit those prefixes and suffixes with regex? I want to match  all 4 digits numbers if they have those prefixes and suffixes, but then returns only the number .

Comment: @mahan The lookbehind `(?<=...)` construct is not yet supported by all JS environments, but all those supporting ECMAScript 2018 will work with [`(?<=\bdigit-|&nbsp;|[\s>]|^)(\d{4})(?=[.?\s<]|-digit\b|&nbsp;|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/DoRRXd/4). If you only work with Chrome/Node.JS, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\s|digit-)([0-9]{4})(?=-digit|\.|\?|\s)
```

You need an `OR` statement at the beginning and end of your query, with four digits in the middle.

To explain further:

- `(?!\s|digit-)` - negative lookahead: either whitespace or `digit-`
- `[0-9]{4}` - a number from 0 to 9, exactly four times
- `(?=-digit|\.|\?|\s)` - positive lookahead: either `-digit`, a `.` (escaped because `.` is a special character in Regex), a question mark (also escaped for the same reason), or whitespace.

[Play around on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xc6nk3/4)

Comment: Without a lookahead, consecutive whitespace separated matches will be left out. You have an obligatory `\s` pattern in the first and third groups.